# synonyms not working at index time in solr

Tags: solr, autocomplete, lucene

For autocomplete, I'm using terms component along with shingle filter which is working fine. Now I want to map synonyms as well.

Earlier I was using faceting and synonyms at query-time were working properly. But now when I added it at index time I'm not getting the right results.

Configuration in schema.xml is as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text_synonyms_category" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
 <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" />
 <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_category.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
 <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" splitOnNumerics="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="1" stemEnglishPossessive="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
 <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_category.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/> <!-- tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>-->
 <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

For example, in synonyms_category.txt I'm having following entries:

```
cat synonyms_category.txt
Iphone=>mobilephones,cases&covers
apple=>mobilephones,tablets,smartwatches
```

But in terms query, on searching iphone its not getting resolved to mobilephones:

```
http://<solr-server>/solr/<core>/terms?terms.fl=category&terms.regex=iphone.*
```

response:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">4</int>
</lst>
<lst name="terms">
<lst name="category"/>
</lst>
</response>
```

Seems terms component is not considering synonyms..not sure if my expectations are correct but as it was working for query type I'm trying it for terms.

Comment: What does the analysis page show? What did you expect? What is in your synonyms file?

Comment: why are you adding synonyms both at index and query time?

Comment: Yes, thats not required. but for testing I did that. My query here is why at index time its not working?